# How to configure the customized nomenclature list environments in tex4ht?

Tags: tex4ht

I am using `tex4ht` to convert a html document.

I configure the list based new environment like `nomenclature` for latex to pdf output. The pdf output and label alignment is good for `nomenclature` environment.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\nomnoteslabel#1{\hspace\labelsep #1}%
\newenvironment{nomenclature}[1]{\list{}{%
        \setlength{\labelwidth}{#1\p@}%
         \setlength{\labelsep}{12\p@}%
          \let\leftmargin\labelwidth%
           \let\makelabel\nomnoteslabel
            \setlength{\itemsep}{\z@}%
             \rmfamily\fontsize{8\p@}{10\p@}\selectfont\raggedright}}%
             {\endlist}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{nomenclature}{30.5}
\item[\textit{x}*] Dimensional coordinates along the channel  
\item[\(k_{\lambda}{_{1w}}\)] Radiation absorption coefficient at the wall 
\item[\(e_{b{\lambda}_{1}}\)]  Plank's function  
\end{nomenclature}

\end{document}
```

I also try to configure the `my.cfg` file to get some customized coding for the `nomenclature` environment.

**my.cfg**

```
\Preamble{xhtml,mathml,NLM,-xtpipes,NoFonts,refcaption,DocBook}

\NewConfigure{nomenclature}{2}
\ConfigureEnv{nomenclature}
   {\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{<def-list>}\ShowPar%
%     \Configure{listings}
%        {\Hcode{<def-item>}}
%        {\Hcode{</def-item>}}
%        {\Hcode{<term>}}
%        {\Hcode{</term>}}
    \bgroup 
    \Configure{HtmlPar}
        {\EndP\HCode{<def><p>}}
        {\EndP\HCode{<def><p>}}
        {\HCode{</p></def>\Hnewline}} 
        {\HCode{</p></def>\Hnewline}}
   }
   {\egroup%
    \ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{</def-list>}\ShowPar%
\par}{}{}%

\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

But I am not get the required customized html tags. I am struggle to configure the list based environment.

**My Current Output:**

```
<def-list>
&#x00A0;    <italic>x</italic>*
      Dimensional
      coordinates
      along
      the
      channel
&#x00A0;    k*
      Radiation
      absorption
      coefficient
      at
      the
      wall
&#x00A0;    e*
      Plank&#8217;s
      function
   </def-list>
```

**My Required Output:**

Each whole `item` (For ex: `\item[\textit{x}*] Dimensional coordinates along the channel`) should be captured `<def-item></def-item>`

Each `item label` (For ex: [\textit{x}*]) should be captured `<term><italic>x*</italic></term>`

Each `item content` (For ex: `Dimensional coordinates along the channel`) should be captured `<def><p>Dimensional coordinates along the channel</def></p>`

The Whole required coding looks like this:

```
<def-list>
<def-item><term>&#x00A0;    <italic>x</italic>*</term>
      <def><p>Dimensional
      coordinates
      along
      the
      channel</p></def></def-item>
<def-item><term>&#x00A0;    k*</term>
      <def><p>Radiation
      absorption
      coefficient
      at
      the
      wall</p></def></def-item>
<def-item><term>&#x00A0;    e*</term>
      <def><p>
      Plank&#8217;s
      function</p></def></def-item>
   </def-list>
```

How to customize configure the list labels and its contents. Kindly advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `\ConfigureList` instead of `\ConfigureEnv` for list environments. From [tex4ht info](http://michal-h21.github.io/src4ht/tex4ht-infose2.html#x7-40002.2):

> ```
> Lists  -----    
> \ConfigureList.....................5
>
> #1   type of list (e.g., itemize, description, enumerate,
>                        list, trivlist)
> #2   before list
> #3   after  list
> #4   before label
> #5   after label
>
> \DeleteMark   removes latex’s label; to be placed at the end of #4
> \AnchorLabel  defines an anchor for \label in current item; to
>               be placed in #5
> ```

So we can just modify your `\ConfigureEnv` a little bit to configure the items:

```
\Preamble{xhtml,mathml,NLM,-xtpipes,NoFonts,refcaption,DocBook}

\Configure{textit}{\HCode{<italic>}}{\HCode{</italic>}}
\Configure{textbf}{\HCode{<bold>}}{\HCode{</bold>}}
\ConfigureList{nomenclature}
   {\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{<def-list>}\ShowPar%
    \bgroup 
    \Configure{HtmlPar}
        {\EndP\HCode{<def><p>}}
        {\EndP\HCode{<def><p>}}
        {\HCode{</p></def>\Hnewline}} 
        {\HCode{</p></def>\Hnewline}}
    \def\EndDefItem{}
   }
   {\EndDefItem\egroup%
    \ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{</def-list>}\ShowPar%
    \par}{\EndDefItem\HCode{<def-item><term>}\def\EndDefItem{\HCode{</def-item>}}}{\HCode{</term>}}%

\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

Only interesting construct is `\EndDefItem` which is defined as empty at beginning of `nomenclature` and it is defined to close `<def-item>` element after first `\item` is used. Note that you also need to use `\EndDefItem` before closing the environment, in order to close the last item. Also note that you don't need `\NewConfigure{nomenclature}`, as you don't use it anywhere.

The result:

```xml
      <def-list>
      <def-item><term>
     <italic>x</italic>*   </term>
      Dimensional
      coordinates
      along
      the
      channel
      </def-item><def-item><term>
     <!--l. 19--><math 
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"  
display="inline" ><mrow 
><msub><mrow 
><mi 
>k</mi><msub><mrow 
></mrow><mrow 
><mi 
>λ</mi></mrow></msub 
></mrow><mrow 
><mn>1</mn><mi 
>w</mi></mrow></msub 
></mrow></math>  </term>
      Radiation
      absorption
      coefficient
      at
      the
      wall
      </def-item><def-item><term>
     <!--l. 20--><math 
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"  
display="inline" ><mrow 
><msub><mrow 
><mi 
>e</mi></mrow><mrow 
><mi 
>b</mi><msub><mrow 
><mi 
>λ</mi></mrow><mrow 
><mn>1</mn></mrow></msub 
></mrow></msub 
></mrow></math>  </term>
      Plank&#x2019;s
      function</def-item></def-list>

</body></html>
```

Comment: Your solution is awesome. Your solution is working excellent.