# htlatex ignores value in brackets in item statement when using itemize

Tags: htlatex, make4ht

In Latex I have the following statements:

```
\begin{itemize}
\item[P)] Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
\item[E)] Pellentesque interdum eros in erat
\item[Q)] Vestibulum ante ipsum primis
\end{itemize}
```

pdflatex produces the following correct output:

[image]

htlatex (HTML output) generates bullets instead of the defined values in the brackets of the item statement:

[image]

Does anyone have an idea how I can get the same output in html as in shown in PDF?

Comment: Maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/274399/how-to-configure-the-customized-nomenclature-list-environments-in-tex4ht can also be applied in your case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TeX4ht removes item labels for `enumerate` and `itemize` by default because HTML doesn't support custom labels in elements that are used to display lists by default.

This is the default configuration for the `itemize` environment:

```
\ConfigureList{itemize}%
   {\EndP\HCode{<ul \a:LRdir
          class="\getClass{itemize}itemize\expandafter\the
          \csname @itemdepth\endcsname">}%
       \afterGetClass{itemize}%
       \PushMacro\end:itm
\global\let\end:itm=\empty}
   {\PopMacro\end:itm \global\let\end:itm \end:itm
\ifvmode \IgnorePar\fi
    \EndP\HCode{</li></ul>}\ShowPar}
   {\end:itm \global\def\end:itm{\EndP\Tg</li>}\DeleteMark}
   {\HCode{<li class="\getClass{li}itemize">}\afterGetClass{li}}
```

It is a bit dense, but the important part is this:

```
   {\end:itm \global\def\end:itm{\EndP\Tg</li>}\DeleteMark}
```

The `\DeleteMark` command removes the label, so we can remove it if we want to keep the label. We also need to produce different elements than `<ul>` and `<li>`, as they don't support custom labels. Instead, we can use just plain `<div>` elements and some CSS for correct rendering.

This configuration file, `mycfg.cfg` contains a modified version of this command with different HTML tags and corresponding CSS:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\catcode`\:=11
\ConfigureList{itemize}%
   {\EndP\HCode{<div \a:LRdir
          class="custom-itemize"><div class="item-head">}%
       \PushMacro\end:itm \global\let\end:itm=\empty}
   {\PopMacro\end:itm \global\let\end:itm \end:itm
\ifvmode \IgnorePar\fi
    \EndP\HCode{</div></div>}\ShowPar}
   {\end:itm \global\def\end:itm{\EndP\Tg</div>\Tg<div class="item-head">}}
   {\HCode{</div><div class="item-content">}}
\Css{.item-head{float:left;width:2em;clear:left;}}
\Css{.item-content{margin-left:2em;}}
\catcode`\:=12
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

Compile using

```
make4ht -c myconfig.cfg filename.tex
```

This is the rendered HTML document:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! This works perfectly.